# Check if values in collection has null value or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following models:

1. **Tour.php** *[belongsTo('App\Region'),belongsTo('App\TourCategory')]*
2. **Region.php** *[hasMany('App\Tour');]*
3. **TourCategory.php** *[hasMany('App\Tour', 'category_id');]*

   And code snippet which does the following tasks:
4. Find **tour category** by it's slug.
5. Get **tours** having that particular category.
6. Get all **unique region names** from those tours.

   ```
     public function fetchByCategory($slug)
     {
      $category = TourCategory::where('slug','=', $slug)->first();
      $tours = $category->tours()->with('region')->get(['region_id']);
      $regions = $tours->pluck('region')->unique();

      return view('frontend.pages.travel-style')
      ->withResults($regions)
      ->withCategory($category);
     }
   ```

But some of my created tour doesn't have region. A null value is set by default when a tour is stored without a region.

This is causing my app to break down as I'm printing my data's in view in the following way:

```
@foreach($results as $region)
    <div class="uk-width-1-2@s">
        <a href="{{ route('region2package',[$category->slug,$region->slug]) }}">
         <div class="uk-height-medium uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-background-cover uk-light" data-src="{{ asset($region->thumb) }}" uk-img>
        </a>
            <h3><a href="{{ route('region2package',[$category->slug,$region->slug]) }}">{{ $region->name }}</a></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

1. When I do dump and die `dd($tours->count());` in the above mentioned method **When there is only one tour in DB saved without region** it returns `1`
2. When I do `dd($regions);` it gives this:

   ```
   Collection {#570 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => null
     ]
    }
   ```

I would be very thankful if anyone could suggest the best possible way to check the items in collection contains null value or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding null value from collection you can filter your collection so null value automatically removed from your collection.

```
$regions = $tours->pluck('region')->unique()->filter();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `has` method on the `tours` relationship to get only the results where `region exists`, something like this:

```
$tours = $category->tours()->has('region')->with('region')->get(['region_id']);
```